# numpy structured array from arbitrary-level nested dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, nested

I have an arbitrary-level nested dictionary that contains field names as keys, and 1-D numpy arrays of the same size as values, e.g.:

```
d = {'a' : arr1, 'b' : {'b1' : arr2, 'b2' : {'c' : arr3}}}
```

Is there a simple way to build a numpy structured array from it that reflects the original hierarchy? Also, would be good to preserve field name ordering if `OrderedDict` is given. The usual `np.array`, `np.asarray`, `np.rec.array` functions do not seem to help.

Comment: Do `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` all have the same dimensions?

Comment: yes, thank you, that's an important aspect, corrected

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're trying to do. In what sense are the data 'hierarchical' if each element in `arr1` has a corresponding element in `arr2` and `arr3`? How do you want to use the array?

Comment: Usual operations, like slicing, comparison, reshaping, copying, etc. Example: `arr = somefunc(d); arr[::2]; arr['b']['b2']['c']`

Comment: I would iterate through the keys creating a matching nested `dtype`. Then create an empty array with this dtype and the common array length.  Finally go back through the dictionary copying array values to the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most generally this can be done in 2 steps.  Construct a compound dtype that corresponds to the dictionary layout.  Then fill an empty array with the arrays from the dictionary.

Construct a sample dictionary:

```
In [94]: arr1=np.arange(10)
In [95]: arr2=np.arange(100.,110.)
In [96]: arr3=np.arange(200,210)
In [98]: d={'a':arr1, 'b':{'b1':arr2, 'b2':{'c':arr3}}}
```

This function constructs the dtype:

```
def mkdt(d):
    ll = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,np.ndarray):
            ll.append((k,v.dtype))
        else:
            ll.append((k,mkdt(v)))
    return ll

In [176]: np.dtype(foo(d))
Out[176]: dtype([('a', '<i4'), ('b', [('b1', '<f8'), ('b2', [('c', '<i4')])])])
```

This function copies data values from `d` to `A`:

```
def copy_values(d, A):
    if A.dtype.names:
        for n in A.dtype.names:
            copy_values(d[n], A[n])
    else:
        A[:]=d

In [264]: A=np.zeros(d['a'].shape,dt)    
In [265]: copy_values(d,A)
In [266]: A
Out[266]: 
array([(0, (100.0, (200,))), (1, (101.0, (201,))), (2, (102.0, (202,))),
       (3, (103.0, (203,))), (4, (104.0, (204,))), (5, (105.0, (205,))),
       (6, (106.0, (206,))), (7, (107.0, (207,))), (8, (108.0, (208,))),
       (9, (109.0, (209,)))], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', [('b1', '<f8'), ('b2', [('c', '<i4')])])])
```

---

(earlier solution)

Here's an interactive (ipython) session that transfers the data from a dictionary like yours to a structured array.

```
In [94]: arr1=np.arange(10)
In [95]: arr2=np.arange(100,110)
In [96]: arr3=np.arange(200,210)
In [98]: d={'a':arr1, 'b':{'b1':arr2, 'b2':{'c':arr3}}}
```

The matching dtype:.

```
In [100]: dt=np.dtype([('a','i'), ('b', np.dtype([('b1','i'),('b2',np.dtype([('c','i')]))]))])
```

Make an empty array of the correct size and type, and fill the fields

```
In [102]: A=np.zeros((10,),dt)    
In [104]: A['a']=d['a']
In [105]: A['b']['b1']=d['b']['b1']
In [106]: A['b']['b2']['c']=d['b']['b2']['c']

In [107]: A
Out[107]: 
array([(0, (100, (200,))), (1, (101, (201,))), (2, (102, (202,))),
       (3, (103, (203,))), (4, (104, (204,))), (5, (105, (205,))),
       (6, (106, (206,))), (7, (107, (207,))), (8, (108, (208,))),
       (9, (109, (209,)))], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', [('b1', '<i4'), ('b2', [('c', '<i4')])])])
```

If all fields are the same dtype (here int), this array could also be constructed as a view on a 2d array:

```
np.column_stack([arr1,arr2,arr3]).view(dt).ravel()
```

This works because the `(10,3)` array has the same data buffer layout as the structured array.

---

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions
```

gives access to some utility functions.

`recfunctions.recursive_fill_fields` for example can copy data from `A` to another array of the same dtype (but not from the `column_stack`.  It uses recursion to handle a nested dtype.

```
In [149]: recfunctions.flatten_descr(dt)
Out[149]: (('a', dtype('int32')), ('b1', dtype('int32')), ('c', dtype('int32')))
```

flattens your nesting.

```
In [150]: recfunctions.get_fieldstructure(dt)
Out[150]: {'a': [], 'b': [], 'b1': ['b'], 'b2': ['b'], 'c': ['b', 'b2']}
```

How these functions handle complex dtypes might be more useful than what they actually do.  Look at the code.

Comment: thanks, works well :) extended it with getting array size at runtime